# how to vertically align a floated image

Tags: html, css, image, vertical-alignment, floating

I have this floated image and I would like to have it on the left of the flex-navbar. The layout should be responsive and the image vertically aligned to the middle (vertically-align: middle; doesn't work).
Thanks in advance!

https://jsfiddle.net/wonrpfsc/

```
<div class="container">
        <a href="#"><img id="logo" src="http://brandmark.io/logo-rank/random/apple.png" alt=""/></a>
    <div id="navbar">
        <a href="#">Home</a>
        <a href="#">About U</a>
        <a href="#">Our Service</a>
        <a href="#">Our Products</a>
        <a href="#">Contac</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
#navbar {
    display: flex;
}

#navbar a {
    flex: 1 1 0;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

#logo {
    width: 10vw;
    height: 10vw;
    float: left;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Comment: Please show an example of your problem using a code example.

Comment: see jsfiddle above

Comment: Sorry. I think I am going blind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try moving the logo into the navbar div like this:

```
'<div class="container">
    <div id="navbar">
       <a href="#"><img id="logo" src="http://brandmark.io/logo-rank/random/apple.png" alt=""/></a>
        <a href="#">Home</a>
        <a href="#">About U</a>
        <a href="#">Our Service</a>
        <a href="#">Our Products</a>
        <a href="#">Contac</a>
    </div>
</div>'
```

And change the CSS like this:

```
#navbar {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
```